# Issue starting activity from non-activity class

Tags: android, class, android-intent, android-activity, static

I am a noob to android and I have a Map Activity that also uses OverlayItems. Within the onButtonTap method of my overlay class, I want to execute startActivity so i can then use intent.ACTION_CALL.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);   
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+MapActivity.phonenumber0));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

in the code above i am asked to create a method for startActivity(Intent), which I don't understand.  and when i try...

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);   
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+MapActivity.phonenumber0));
MapActivity.startActivity(callIntent);
```

It says i cannot make a static reference to a non static reference to a non-static method.  And when I try to use the context of the object, which is the button being tapped it won't allow me to do so.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);   
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+MapActivity.phonenumber0));
ContextObj.startActivity(callIntent);
```

And of course moving this block of code to the main Activity requires a static method which presents its own set of issues.

How can set the appropriate context for startActivity? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can create method in your MapActivity class like this to get context...

**Edit :**
Take some static variable like this...

```
public static Context mContext;
```

In Activity's onCreate() method assign base context to it...

```
mContext = getBaseContext();
```

& return mContext...

```
public static Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}
```

& call it in to your non activity class to start activity...

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);   
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+MapActivity.phonenumber0));
MapActivity.getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: the editor says I can't make a static reference to getBasecontext

Comment: Got it to work! Just had to add intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this before start the activity set this flag :

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the context of the activity (Map Activity) to your class and then use it..

Comment: in the constructor of the other class..if you provide more code i can help

Comment: public class MapActivity extends MapActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener, LocationListener, OnCheckedChangeListener.. is all i have for the other class.  Do I create a public class for startActivity?