# Jumping from Class to a New Activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am making a Flappy Bird for my project. Almost all the parts are done but i'm **stuck** at the final part. My **goal** is launch (**An activity from game over class which displays the score, player name and store this data on the database** ). I can do the storing to database part easily if i know how to launch the **that new Activity somwhow.**

If i need to upload somethings more, please tell me

**I tried:**

[Issue starting activity from non-activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319631/issue-starting-activity-from-non-activity-class)

[How can I start an Activity from a non-Activity class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298225/how-can-i-start-an-activity-from-a-non-activity-class)

But still no solution! I will upload the code of the game over class:
My thought is to start that new Activity from this class:

I tried the above link's code in diffrent parts of the class but the game doesn't give is stuck at the game over screen.

```
public class GamePlayScene implements Scene{

    int cHeight;
    int cWidth;

    float x;
    float y;

    private Rect r = new Rect();

    private Player player;
    private Point playerPoint;
    private ObstacleManager obstacleManager;
    private boolean movingPlayer = false;
    private boolean gameOver = false;
    private long gameOverTime;

    public GamePlayScene(){
        player = new Player(new Rect(100,100,200,200), Color.rgb(255,0,0));
        //starting position of the player
        playerPoint = new Point(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/2,3*Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/4);
        player.update(playerPoint);
        //make gamePanel focusable so it can handle events
        obstacleManager = new ObstacleManager(Color.BLACK);         //control the rectangles height width and gap
    }

    public void reset(){

        //starting position of the player
        playerPoint = new Point(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/2,3*Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/4);
        player.update(playerPoint);
        obstacleManager = new ObstacleManager(Color.BLACK);
        movingPlayer = false;
        score = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void terminate(){
        SceneManager.ACTIVE_SCENE = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);  //makes our canvas white except our player is red

        player.draw(canvas);
        obstacleManager.draw(canvas);

        if(gameOver){
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setTextSize(70);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            x = cWidth / 2f - r.width() / 2f - r.left;
            y = cHeight / 2f + r.height() / 2f - r.bottom;
            drawCenterText(canvas,paint,"Game Over");

            x = cWidth / 2.4f - r.width() / 2f - r.left;
            y = cHeight / 1.9f + r.height() / 1f - r.bottom;
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize(65);
            drawCenterText(canvas,paint,"Click To Replay");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(){
        if (!gameOver) {
            player.update(playerPoint);
            obstacleManager.update();
            if(obstacleManager.playerCollide(player)){
                gameOver = true;
                gameOverTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override           //waiting after the game is over
    public void receiveTouch(MotionEvent event){
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(!gameOver && player.getRectangle().contains((int) event.getX(), (int)event.getY()))
                    movingPlayer = true;
                if(gameOver && System.currentTimeMillis() - gameOverTime >= 2000){
                    reset();
                    gameOver = false;
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(!gameOver && movingPlayer)
                    playerPoint.set((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                movingPlayer = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    //DRAWING GAME OVER TEXT
    private void drawCenterText(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, String text) {
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        canvas.getClipBounds(r);
         cHeight = r.height();
         cWidth  = r.width();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), r);
        canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
    }
}
```

**Class that make the object of GamePlayscene**

```
public class SceneManager {
    private ArrayList<Scene> scenes = new ArrayList<>();
    public static int ACTIVE_SCENE;

    public SceneManager( ){
        ACTIVE_SCENE = 0;
        scenes.add(new GamePlayScene());
    }

    public void recieveTouch(MotionEvent event){
        scenes.get(ACTIVE_SCENE).receiveTouch(event);
    }

    public void update(){
        scenes.get(ACTIVE_SCENE).update();
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        scenes.get(ACTIVE_SCENE).draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass Context to `GamePlayScene` class for starting new Activity

Comment: I extended the Activity class on the GamePlayScene and then used  getApplicationContext(), with the Intent .. .But still no activity was launched

Comment: If you have any `View` in the class, just use that `view.getContext()` to get the context

Comment: @AkshayBhat No i don't have View in the class.. it's just a class that doesn't  Extends or Implement Activity or View or other class from the library

Comment: Do you want to start activity from `GamePlayScene.class`?

Comment: @AkshayBhat Yes

Comment: Post the code where you create `GamePlayScene` Object.

Comment: @AkshayBhat okay, but it has almost nothing in it! it's like a manager.. I will edit

Comment: Ok, I think you have many classes. In the activity you will be creating a main object to set it as view, so in that constructor pass the context and continue to pass the context in constructor until you get it in your `GamePlayScene.class` constructor. Then you can have a member variable context in `GamePlayScene.class` with which you can start activity.

Comment: Is Scene a class which extends View object? Also are you calling SceneManager from any Activity class?

Comment: @HiltonKhadka: if `Scene` extending View class then try to you `this.getContext()`

Comment: @HiltonKhadka: or change `public SceneManager( ){
        ACTIVE_SCENE = 0;
        scenes.add(new GamePlayScene());
    }` to `public SceneManager( Context context){
        ACTIVE_SCENE = 0;
        scenes.add(new GamePlayScene(context));
    }`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK it's working :) ... thank you guys :)